# Why does UdpClient.Receive require a ref parameter?

Tags: .net, sockets, pass-by-reference

Why is the parameter on [UpdClient.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx) a `ref` parameter, instead of simply `out`?

According to the MSDN page, the parameter is filled with the address that the datagram was sent from. However it doesn't specify what kind of input it is used for, only output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like one of those (remarkably rare) BCL inconsistencies/discrepancies.  This parameter is not used as input in the method at all (as shown by [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)).

Perhaps this was not always the case and they kept using `ref` instead of switching to `out` to preserve backwards compatibility.

Comment: I don't believe keeping the method signature but changing funcionality would preserve any kind of backwards compatibility. So, either they broke compatibility and forgot to fix the signature (highly unlikely), or it was always like that...